# Convert String to Python List of Dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

Is there a library function to convert string in below format to python list of dictionary ?

**Input:**

```
data[0][value]=123&data[0][Type]=Range&data[1][value]=345&data[1][Type]=Fixed
```

**Output**

```
data = [{'value':123,'Type':'Range'},{'value':456,'Type':'Fixed'}]
```

where input is of type str and output is of type list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
inp = 'data[0][value]=123&data[0][Type]=Range&data[1][value]=345&data[1][Type]=Fixed'

matches = re.findall(r'\[([0-9]+)\]\[([a-zA-Z]+)\]=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', inp)

out = {}
for match in matches:
    index, key, value = match
    if out.get(index) is None:
        out[index] = {}
    out[index][key] = value

data = out.values()
```

which will give you

`[{'Type': 'Fixed', 'value': '345'}, {'Type': 'Range', 'value': '123'}]`